# Flutter FCM problem: notification not appearing

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use Firebase Cloud Messaging to set up push notifications for my app. I'm trying to start of simple by manually sending a notification payload and have it handled as a background notification in the android app. However, no notification appears in the emulator.

This is my current main.dart code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:redue/Screens/Welcome%20Screen/WelcomeScreen.dart';
import 'pages/menu.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'pages/settings.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'pages/settings.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  Location location = new Location();

  bool _serviceEnabled;
  PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;

  _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
  if (!_serviceEnabled) {
    _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
  if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
    _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
    if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      return null;
    }
  }
  _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
    print('Message data: ${message.data}');

    if (message.notification != null) {
      print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
    }
  });
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentTheme.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "ReDue",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: WelcomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm also using cloud firestore in my app as well as google services (why I ask for the location). I should also note that when I open the app in the emulator I have not recieved a notification permission method and in the firebase console when I publish the notification it says the notification has zero sends.

Comment: Push notifications do not work on emulator try on device connect your phone and run the build you can also try using One signal service with firebase for easy setup and it's free for restricted features

Comment: That is not correct @SunilKumar - push notifications work on emulators. See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message?hl=en

Comment: @ReDue are you using the correct fcm token?

Comment: Try on real device it will work same code

Comment: If you still need help please try this: https://medium.com/multiverse-software/flutter-push-notification-using-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-396fd438d9da